# Why AppDomain.ShadowCopyFiles is string?

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library, shadow-copy

There is ShadowCopy functionality in .Net to preserve file locking by copying assemblies.
There are two properties:

1. [`AppDomain.ShadowCopyFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.shadowcopyfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that uses AppDomainSetup
2. [`AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.shadowcopyfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that stores it in internal `string[]`

`AppDomainSetup` has `string Value[]` field, that used for storing configuration. The strange thing for me is that `AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles` is a string property, and we need to set `"true"` or `"false"` instead of real `bool` type.

Here is an implementation for that property in `AppDomainSetup`:

```
public string ShadowCopyFiles
{
  get
  {
    return this.Value[8];
  }
  set
  {
    if (value != null && string.Compare(value, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
      this.Value[8] = value;
    else
      this.Value[8] = (string) null;
  }
}
```

And here is an implementation for AppDomain.ShadowCopyFiles:

```
public bool ShadowCopyFiles 
{ 
    get {
        String s = FusionStore.ShadowCopyFiles; 
        if((s != null) &&
           (String.Compare(s, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    } 
}
```

But why in `AppDomainSetup` this property is a `string`? Why Microsoft didn't used the some `bool` conversion logic as in `AppDomain.ShadowCopyFiles`?

It strange that such a bit smelly code located in `AppDomainSetup`, and I was just thinking is there a real reason for that that I'm missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862434/why-is-appdomainsetup-shadowcopyfiles-a-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a mistake in the early versions of .NET and MS have decided not to fix it as it would break existing code.

See this link.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/295269/appdomainsetup-shadowcopyfiles-should-be-of-the-type-bool-instead-of-string